# How can resolve navigation constraint warning?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I am some issues with xcode in uinavigation controller constraint. It throw some warning but can not be resolved. Is it a bug or can be solved another way.

Comment: UINavigtionController constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't affect to your layout but if you want to hide or remove that warning then you can change simulated matric From **Inferred** To **Freedom** for NavigationController in storyboard.

[image]

**After remove warning select again Inferred**